# Ge User Profile Information using Instagram Basic Display API

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have found a way to get the Instagram feed of a profile using Instagram Basic Display API. However, I can not retrieve the user profile data such as the number of followers, the Instagram profile picture, etc. Is there any way to get this data using the Instagram Basic Display API?

This post is similar with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63085452/how-to-use-new-instagram-graph-or-basic-display-api-to-fetch-profile-image-of-a) but I want to get all the information of my account's profile without using a scraper.

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the followers count with Instagram Basic Display API. You can get the user profile like this:

```
$url = 'https://graph.instagram.com/'.$user_id.'/?';
                 $data = array('access_token'  => $long_lived_access_token, 'fields'=> 'username');
                 $string = http_build_query($data);
                 $ch = curl_init($url.$string);
                 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                 $result = curl_exec($ch);
                 curl_close($ch);
```